# In Broad White South African English, voiceless plosives tend to be unaspirated in all positions, which serves as a marker of this subvariety.[

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

I'm not sure what this sentence means.

I think Voiceless plosive/Stop are /p/, /t/, and /k/.

So do words ending with "t" - (like  Hit, Sit, Last) - not have any air released at the end?

In Korean words like ending in p,t,k have no air released but I dont think this happens in SA English, this sounds odd.

Answer (score 3):

Aspiration in English is characteristically associated with plosives at the start of stressed syllables, as in the words *pore, tone, cane.* According to the sentence you quoted in the title of your question, a speaker of "Broad White South African English" would use unaspirated [p], [t], [k] in these words and others like them, unlike speakers of most other English varieties who would use aspirated [pʰ], [tʰ], [kʰ].

To be honest, the difference between aspiration and audible release in word-final position is not entirely clear to me, but I wrote a bit about what I think it might be in my answer to an [ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159474/can-i-make-an-unaspirated-t-sound-in-the-words-like-best-chest-belt-et/159485#159485). I doubt the author of the sentence that you're asking about was thinking of word-final plosives in particular.